# system commands as per user logged in

Tags: php, logging

I have a situation wherein, the user logs into the website based on the ldap credentials. Now I have to execute few commands in the backend for this user.

I checked running php script which executes "whoami" command from the browser. It seems by default it runs it as apache not as the user who has logged in.

Is there any way that I can run the shell commands as the user who as logged in?

Comment: It depends on the rest of your system.  What OS is your server running? Do the users have local accounts or just remote ones?

Comment: Its Red hat linux. The users login thru NIS authentication.

Comment: Please search for `sudo` and `php` on this website first. This question has been asked and answered already.